# Mac performance issues and dyld cache

Tags: macos, performance

I have MacbookPro mid 2012, Sierra 10.12.4, 512 GB HDD (the initial factory disk), and 16GB RAM (2x8GB, memory was upgraded from the initial 4GB).

Periodically I get the spinning pinwheel of death (SPOD). Most of the time only a single application (the one I'm actively using at the moment) hangs. I can still move the app's window, cmd+TAB switch to another app and do something there, then return to the original app after it has unfrozen. CleanMyMac notifies me that the app has stopped responding. Sometimes though, my system just freezes completely, even the mouse can't be moved. It becomes responsive again after ~10-15 seconds.

I've tried

- running disk utility and SMART utility - no disk errors
- cleaning caches in `~/Library/Cache` - sometimes it helps but not for too long.
- there are no CPU or memory intensive tasks in Activity Monitor. However, AM itself freezes sometimes.
- there are no distinctive messages in `/var/log/system.log` before/after the SPOD
- booting in recovery mode and then rebooting in normal mode - it helps for sometime.

However the most useful trick I've discovered is

```
$ sudo update_dyld_shared_cache -force
```

(no messages are displayed while running). It actually helps for ~half a day of active usage.

Now as I understand the dyld cache is a kind of database of dynamically linked libraries. But I don't have enough expertise to draw any further conclusions and googling does not help much.

If the problem is indeed in dyld cache why does it keep getting corrupted? How can I fix it?

Comment: I am having the exact same problem. Would love to get an answer from somone. Please.

Comment: @GregWaddell I had an issue with hdd - to - logic board cable. After replacing it with a new one, macbook works fine. I suggest you get a hdd-to-usb connector, open your macbook, disconnect hdd from the existing cable and test it via usb to verify the root cause.